# How to debug CUDA kernels in Visual Studio 2010 without monitor halting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, cuda, nsight

I have CUDA 6.5 SDK with Parallel Nsight 4.2 installed on Win7 x64. I want to debug my CUDA kernels, but my monitor halts at break points.

In my Nsigt montior options under CUDA menu I have

Desktop GPU must use SW preemption: true

Headless GPU must use SW preemption: true

TCC GPU must use SW preemption: true

And in my VS 2010 Nsight Cuda options I have

Preemption preference: Prefer NO SW preeption

I tried SW preemption in VS 2010 Nsight settings but same thing the monitor halts.

It's not related with code because I was able to debug in Linux using nsight eclipse using the beta feature to be able to debug using 1 GPU.But I prefer to work in Windows.

Comment: Please try to use default setting. on the other hand, please add more steps for how to repro your issue, and what's your system's configuration, like OS, driver version, GPU, etc. That give more precise description about your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Nsight Monitor settings in Geenral tab I  changed

WDDM TDR enabled to false and now it seems to be working.

I am using NVIDIA GTX 970 GPU and NVidia Driver 344.75.